# JavaScript - How to make an eyeball that follows the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an eyeball that follows the mouse around using only html, css, and javascript. Currently, I have the eyeball rendered and even got the pupil to move around when you hover over the eye. Unfortunately, the pupil is not moving in the direction of the mouse at all & will only begin moving when you hover over the eyeball itself.

I am not worried about the location or size of the eye right now, just trying to get everything working. I have tried to setup an event listener in javascript using 'mousemove' then getting the vertical and horizontal access using 'getBoundingClientRect()'. Then I believe you should be able to calculate the rotation of the pupil using some equations I found using the mouseX & mouseY values from the 'mousemove' but this is where I get stuck & I believe it is also where the problem is occurring. I will be attaching my code below. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const eyeball = document.querySelectorAll('.eye-inner');
  [].forEach.call(eyeball, function(eye) {
    let mouseX = eye.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let mouseY = eye.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let radianDegrees = Math.atan2(e.pageX - mouseX, e.pageY - mouseY);
    let rotationDegrees = radianDegrees * (180 / Math.PI) * -1 + 180;

    eye.style.transform = `rotate(${rotationDegrees}deg)`;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  background: black;
}

.eye {
  display: flex;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 41px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 75% 0;
  transform: translate(300%, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.eye-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.pupil {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="eye">
    <div class="eye-inner">
      <div class="pupil"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I change -300% to 0 to make the eye not leave the viewport

Comment: Checkout this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGe3pS5LqEw
The guy pretty much did what you want to do, maybe it helps you.

Comment: your code works, but the problem is in the div space with class `container` because of the absolute `.eye`. Try setting a specific width and height for `.container`.